# How to log MassTransit published messages/internal errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a .Net 4.8 web application on IIS that once called uses MassTransit to publish a message to RabbitMQ queue. Everything works most of the time but there are cases (like 1 in 10) when I have no idea why nothing is published. I have a debug logging right before/after publish and the "after" is never fired. No exceptions, no nothing.

```
// Constructor, fired on each request - maybe it's better to have static one?
public QueueLibHelper()
{
    var cfg = ConfigHelper.GetConfig();
    bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => 
        x.Host(new Uri(cfg.Host),
            h => {
                h.Heartbeat(15);
                h.Username(cfg.UserName); 
                h.Password(cfg.Password);
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cfg.Nodes))
                {
                    string[] nodes = cfg.Nodes.Split(',');
                    h.UseCluster(c =>
                    {
                        foreach (var n in nodes)
                        {
                            c.Node(n);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }));
    bus.Start();
}

//  Sending to queue, 
public void UpdatePmtToQueue(long paymentId, string status)
{
    var message = new InputData() { Id = paymentId, Status = status };
    MassTransit.Util.TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish<IInputData>(message));
    StopBus();
}
```

I assume it might be connected to the whole async/await situation. I tried also `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but that approach had a ton of different problems. Maybe bus is somehow closed before the publish actually runs?
I tried to add MT logging like this, but no log is being written:

```
<source name="MassTransit" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Console" type="MassTransit.Logging.Tracing.ConsoleTraceListener, MassTransit" />
      <add name="Xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="MassTransit.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong or at least how to see what MassTransit is doing (failing) internally?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` for log output, any logging framework that integrates with it should work.

It's also typical to start the bus at application start time, and leave it running until the application exits, at which time the bus should be stopped to ensure all pending messages have been delivered.

MassTransit is very async, it uses the TPL heavily. So if you're trying to cross the chasm from sync to async, TaskUtil.Await() works most of the time but mileage varies.